# Inject Angular factory dependency into Typescript class without polluting constructor?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm writing an factory as a Typescript class and instantiating it with `new FactoryName()` when needed.

I'm getting it working as a factory by doing this: `.factory('FactoryName', function() { return FactoryName; })` and it works great, but now I need to inject another factory I've made outside of Typescript into it without polluting the constructor call. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

```
export function FactoryName(injectedService1, injectedService2) {
  return class FactoryClass {
    constructor() {
      let test = injectedService1.testFunction();
    }
  }
}

app.factory('FactoryName', FactoryName)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
app.factory('FactoryName', ['...', (...deps) => new FactoryName(...deps)]);
```

Since anonymous functions don't play well with `$inject` annotation, array annotation suits the case better.